# Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014

I have the following procedure to update my booking and other related tables.

But we often get the error

`Transaction (Process ID 51) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateBookingDetails] (
     @ParmsList
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION UPDATEBOOKINGTRAN


            UPDATE Booking          

            SET @RecordsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT   

            INSERT INTO Payment 

            DELETE  FROM AdditionalBookingCategories

            INSERT AdditionalBookingCategories 

            DELETE FROM BookingAssistants

            INSERT INTO BookingAssistants 

            DELETE FROM BookingResource

            INSERT BookingResource 


        COMMIT TRANSACTION UPDATEBOOKINGTRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION UPDATEBOOKINGTRAN

            PRINT 'Error detected, all changes reversed'
        END

        -- ERROR HANDLING - Grab Error code and throw  
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
            ,@ErrorProc NVARCHAR(126)
            ,@ErrorLineNo INT;

        SELECT @ErrorLineNo = ERROR_LINE()
            ,@ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ,@ErrorProc = ERROR_PROCEDURE();

        RAISERROR (
                'Error %s occurred in %s. Line  %d'
                ,16
                ,1
                ,@ErrorMessage
                ,@ErrorProc
                ,@ErrorLineNo
                )
        WITH SETERROR;
    END CATCH
END
```

I couldn't find out what is the problem with my procedure. It looks ok, but how the deadlock appears? Is anything I am missing in my procedure to handle the deadlock?

It happens rarely but atleast 5 times a day. I couldn't replicate as it requires simultaneous update.

Comment: How many records were inserted and deleted in each table ?

Comment: Start by looking at the [deadlock graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx)